# Тригер В phpmyadmin

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

Создаю тригер в phpmyadmin на удаление,но у меня выскакивает ошибка #1064
Не могу понять, что не так?

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `delete_klient` BEFORE DELETE ON `klienti`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
DELETE FROM `zakazi` WHERE `id_klient`=OLD.`id`;
END
```

Comment: Приведите текст ошибки.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте без BEGIN и END:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `delete_klient` BEFORE DELETE ON `klienti`
 FOR EACH ROW DELETE from `zakazi` WHERE `id_klient`= OLD.`id`
```

Еще, убедитесь, что названия таблиц совпадают, они чувствительны к регистру.

Вообще, без самого сообщения об ошибке сложно сказать, в чем проблема.